# Rounding in R without loosing the trailing zero, when it is part of the significant figure

Tags: r, rounding, significant-digits

I am looking for rounding up behaviour for numbers like 0.1298 to be displayed as 0.130 while keeping the trailing zero as a significant digit. This also needs to work for tables where the length of the decimals is different. I use signif() to round the data and it works fine except R loses the trailing zero, but it is needed for accuracy. Is there a working function for this?

does anyone have a good idea for me? Thanks a lot already!

I have tried modifying signif

```
mod_signif <- function(x,digits) {
   sprintf(paste0('%#.',3,'g'), signif(x,digits))}
```

and this works fine for numbers up to 5 decimal places, after which the scientific writing kicks in.

```
> mod_signif(0.129554,3)
[1] "0.130"
> mod_signif(0.0129554,3)
[1] "0.0130"
> mod_signif(0.00129554,3)
[1] "0.00130"
> mod_signif(0.000129554,3)
[1] "0.000130"
> mod_signif(0.0000129554,3)
[1] "1.30e-05"
```

I would expect 0.0000130 in this case

If I try to counteract this with the format() function, I start going in circles because then i am going back to numeric and lose the zero again....

Comment: Try `formatC(x, digits = 3, format = "fg", drop0trailing = FALSE, flag = "#")` The "fg" format uses significant digit rounding, and the flag and drop0trailing args seem to keep trailing zeros.

Comment: I didn't check for dupilcates! @NicChr's comment is v. similar to the concise, accepted answer of the question that I've linked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `scales::label_number()`. Because of the way the labelers within the scales package work, this requires creating a function within the body of another function.

Also note that you'll need to do some simple arithmetic to convert from arguments that `signif()` expects to those that `label_number()` expects.

```r
library(scales)

label_nicely <- function(number, digits){
  
  ## I stole this from the documentation for base::round
  ## Pretty neat, huh?
  round_to <- digits - ceiling(log10(abs(number)))
  
  value <- round(number, round_to)
  
  ## accuracy is expected to be (e.g.) 0.01 rather than, say, 3
  accuracy_arg <- 1 / 10^round_to
  
  ## Construct a labeller within the function run
  labeller <- label_number(accuracy = accuracy_arg)
  
  label <- labeller(value)
  
    return(label)
} 

label_nicely(0.129554,3)
#> [1] "0.130"
label_nicely(0.0000129554, 3)
#> [1] "0.0000130"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Edit:
The description of `base::round` tell us that `signif(n, x)` is equivalent to `round(n, x - ceiling(log10(abs(n)))`. Using that trick, we can convert from 'significant digits' to 'actual digits', which we can pass to the `accuracy` argument of `label_number()` to get the required behaviour.

Comment: thank you very much! this seems to work fine too 

The solution of NicChr also seems to work fine

learned something new again!

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Could you please confirm (to the system) that this question is a dupe of the linked question? It will help people who find this question to get the answers they need